# Diablo III - Imperial gem drops at level ~13?

Tags: diablo-iii, pc

So I played D3 when it came out for a couple of months and haven't touched it since. I have picked it back up again and started a new character with a friend. I looked up how to get to Whimsyshire since I had a wand of herding in my inventory.

We were about level 13 and ran through whimsyshire. We opened up either some presents or a happy cloud, and out dropped a load of Imperial gems. I thought "OK, I remember gems, you socket them in stuff and you can combine them". It's only after getting back to town I realised that in all the hours I played before, I got to some Perfect Square gems as the highest level, and these Imperial gems are significantly higher level than those, dropping at player level 13 on Normal difficulty.

So my question is... what the hell just happened? Was it supposed to happen? Did they change things that much in the last few years that these things just drop for free? Is there a way I can get more?

Comment: I don't know the specifics on gem drops nowadays, but it is a *completely* different game now, that's for sure.

Comment: The loot table is different.

Answer (score 5):

I think you were only getting Imperial gems because you were in Whimsyshire.

There are actually two secret levels now: Whimsyshire and Whimsydale. Both are visually the same (rainbows, clouds, unicorns, etc.). You still access Whimsyshire by using the Staff of Herding in Act I. You access Whimsydale by killing a rainbow goblin in Adventure mode (he won't appear in rifts or greater rifts).

The main difference between the two zones is that in Whimsydale you get lots and lots of gems and loot, while Whimsyshire has more typical loot drops.

If you were in Whimsydale I could see that explaining the Imperial gems, but I wouldn't expect higher level gems to drop in Whimsyshire. Maybe you found a bug since most of the focus on Diablo 3 is on the level 70 end game rather than leveling up?

In any event, I wouldn't expect you to find any Imperial gems in general until you are at least level 61, as stated elsewhere.

Comment: From what I've read, Imperial gems should only be available in the Reaper of Souls expansion? I don't own RoS, just the base game.

Comment: In the second paragraph you called both maps Whimsydale

Comment: @WhatEvil The main restriction is you'd need to be level 61 for them to drop, they don't check your client (since implicitly you'd need to be in RoS to hit 61).  They probably overlooked Whimsyshire/Whimsydale when they revamped the loot tables for those zones since the percentage of players without RoS is small.  Note how those zones use special chest types you don't see anywhere else.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking maybe that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't played the game since it came out, the game is totally different. Basically just erase everything from your memory.

Gem drops scale up to your level, and starting at level 61, you get marquise gems if you are playing on T1 or higher difficulty.

So yes, this was supposed to happen and you'll find a ton of them. There are even gem-only goblins in the game that will drop plans for gems along with a bunch of random gems.

Bonus: You'll also be able to click on a single gem of a specific level and pick up all gems around you in a certain radius. Example: You clicked on a marquise gem and you'll automatically pick up all marquise gems in a 30 meter radius around you.

Comment: But I'm not level 61, and I was on Normal difficulty.

Comment: I'm just giving you extra information in addition to your original question. All drops scale to your level and then once you hit level 61, you need to be on T1 to get marquise gems.

Comment: Aren't marquise gems lower than Imperial though?